# Last element added to a D3 bar chart doesn't sort

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm a D3 / Javascript noob and am trying to create a chart with the option to add bars (via an Update > Enter selection) and then subsequently re-sort them.

However, the last bar added refuses to participate in the re-sorting.

Can anybody tell me:
a) why this happens 
b) how to fix it

See the Codepen: https://codepen.io/benjamesdavis/pen/JjodJwy?editors=1010

```
            //Width and height
            var w = 900;
            var h = 450;

            var array = [ 5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,
                            11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25 ];

            dataset=[];             
            for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++)
                {dataset[i] = {"key":i, "value": array[i]}}

            var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
                            .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
                            .rangeRound([0, w])
                            .paddingInner(0.05);

            var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                            .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, d=> d.value)])
                            .range([0, h]);

            //Create SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);



            //Create bars
            svg.selectAll("rect")
               .data(dataset)
               .enter()
               .append("rect")
               .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return xScale(i);
               })
               .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return h - yScale(d.value);
               })
               .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
               .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return yScale(d.value);
               })
               .attr("fill", function(d) {
                    return "rgb(0, 0, " + Math.round(d.value * 10) + ")";
               });




            //On click, update with new data            
            d3.select("#newBar")
                .on("click", function() {

                    //Add one new value to dataset
                    var maxValue = 25;
                    var newNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxValue);
                    newNumber = {"key":dataset.length, "value": newNumber}
                    dataset.push(newNumber);

                    //Update scale domains
                    xScale.domain(d3.range(dataset.length));
                    yScale.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, d=> d.value)]);

                    //Select…
                     bars = svg.selectAll("rect")
                        .data(dataset)

                    //Enter…
                    bars.enter()
                        .append("rect")
                        .attr("x", w)
                        .attr("y", function(d) {
                            return h - yScale(d.value);
                        })
                        .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
                        .attr("height", function(d) {
                            return yScale(d.value);
                        })
                        .attr("fill", function(d,i) {
                            return "rgb(0, 0, " + Math.round(d.value * 10) + ")";
                        })
                        .merge(bars)
                        .transition()
                        .duration(500)
                        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                            return xScale(i);
                        })
                        .attr("y", function(d) {
                            return h - yScale(d.value);
                        })
                        .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
                        .attr("height", function(d) {
                            return yScale(d.value);
                        });

                });


            //Re-Sort Bars
            d3.select("#sortBars").on("click",function(){
                d3.shuffle(dataset)

                 bars.data(dataset,d => d.key)
                    .transition(2000)
                    .attr("x", function(d, i) {             
                        return xScale(i);
                    })                                  
                })
```

Comment: I think it's to do with your variable 'bars' scope.

Comment: You're correct.

If I change "bars.data" to "svg.selectAll("rect").data" in my sort code, it works. Not 100% sure what the difference between those selections is though.

`//Re-Sort Bars
   d3.select("#sortBars").on("click",function(){
    d3.shuffle(dataset)

     svg.selectAll("rect").data(dataset,d => d.key)
     .transition(2000)
     .attr("x", function(d, i) {    
      return xScale(i);
     })         
    })`

Answer (score 2):

The specific issue is that when you `enter()` the `bars` selection on line 70 and merge it into `bars` on 83, you’re not saving the new, merged selection back into `bars`. As a result, when you re-sort on line 104, the `bars` update selection doesn’t contain the newest bar.

In general, the thing to remember is that a data-bound selection is always the update selection, and selections are (as of D3v4) immutable, so when you you do

```
bars.enter()
    .<do stuff to just the enter selection>
    .merge(bars) // merge the update and enter selections together
    .<do more stuff to the merged update+enter selections>
```

the value of `bars` is still the old update selection. You have to explicitly save the merged selection if you want to do more stuff with it later.

```
bars = bars.enter() // note the assignment to bars!
    .<do stuff to just the enter selection>
    .merge(bars) // merge the update and enter selections together
    .<do more stuff to the merged update+enter selections>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the fact that when you define bars, it's in the scope of the add-bars function, not the re-sort function, so firstly, you need to do the select each time. Then, you need to make sure you are using the key both times. Here's my take on your code:

//Width and height
        var w = 500;
        var h = 200;

```
    var array = [ 5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,
                    11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25 ];

    dataset=[];     

    for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {dataset[i] = {"key":i, "value": array[i]}}

    var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
                    .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
                    .rangeRound([0, w])
                    .paddingInner(0.05);

    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, d=> d.value)])
                    .range([0, h]);

    //Create SVG element
    var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);



    //Create bars
    svg.selectAll("rect")
       .data(dataset)
       .enter()
       .append("rect")
       .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return xScale(i);
       })
       .attr("y", function(d) {
            return h - yScale(d.value);
       })
       .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
       .attr("height", function(d) {
            return yScale(d.value);
       })
       .attr("fill", function(d) {
            return "rgb(0, 0, " + Math.round(d.value * 10) + ")";
       });




    //On click, update with new data            
    d3.select("#newBar")
        .on("click", function() {

            //Add one new value to dataset
            var maxValue = 25;
            var newNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxValue);
            newNumber = {"key":dataset.length, "value": newNumber}
            dataset.push(newNumber);

            //Update scale domains
            xScale.domain(d3.range(dataset.length));
            yScale.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, d=> d.value)]);

            //Select…
             bars = svg.selectAll("rect")
                       .data(dataset,d => d.key) //make sure you use the key here too!


            //Enter…
            bars.enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", w)
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return h - yScale(d.value);
                })
                .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
                .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return yScale(d.value);
                })
                .attr("fill", function(d,i) {
                    return "rgb(0, 0, " + Math.round(d.value * 10) + ")";
                })
                .merge(bars)
                .transition()
                .duration(500)
                .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return xScale(i);
                })
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return h - yScale(d.value);
                })
                .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
                .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return yScale(d.value);
                });

        });


    //Re-Sort Bars
    d3.select("#sortBars").on("click",function(){
        d3.shuffle(dataset)
        bars =  svg.selectAll("rect").data(dataset,d => d.key) //redefine bars, and use the key
            .transition(2000)
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {             
                return xScale(i);
            })                                  
        })
```